# sprintf cause my program stop working in keil

Tags: c, printf, stm32, keil

This is my main function and I don't know why when I simulate it in proteos I figured that the code runs up to sprintf and next lines doesn't run and when I comment it the "salam" printed on lcd
I use mingw compiler and I have installed all librarys
int main(void)
{
/* USER CODE BEGIN 1 */

/* USER CODE END 1 */

/* MCU Configuration--------------------------------------------------------*/

```
/* Reset of all peripherals, Initializes the Flash interface and the Systick. */
HAL_Init();

/* USER CODE BEGIN Init */

/* USER CODE END Init */

/* Configure the system clock */
SystemClock_Config();

/* USER CODE BEGIN SysInit */

/* USER CODE END SysInit */

/* Initialize all configured peripherals */
MX_GPIO_Init();
/* USER CODE BEGIN 2 */
char q[5] = "salam" ;
int a = 6541;
//float b = a/7;
LCD1602_Begin8BIT(RS_GPIO_Port,RS_Pin,E_Pin,D0_GPIO_Port,D0_Pin,D1_Pin,D2_Pin,D3_Pin,D4_GPIO_Port,D4_ 
Pin,D5_Pin,D6_Pin,D7_Pin);
LCD1602_setCursor(1,1);

//snprintf(q, 20, "%10d", 1234567);
//LCDCHAR_Puts(0, 0, q);    
//char command1[50], command2[50]; // Added
//char *temp[] = {NULL, command1, command2, NULL}; // Modified
//temp[0]="sum";
    
LCD1602_print("mahdi kahrizi");
    
    
LCD1602_2ndLine();
sprintf(q,"%d",a);
LCD1602_print(q);
```

Comment: did you remember to have the statement: `#include <string.h>` at the top of the file?

Answer (score 1):

the problem starts from here.

```
char q[5] = "salam" ;
```

`q` is too short to store this word. It has to be at least 6 chars long.

It is Undefined Behaviour as you write outside the array bounds.

When you change the length of the `q` to be longer

```
snprintf(q, sizeof(q), "%d", a);
```